# How to move the documentactions viewlet from a viewletmanager to another?

Tags: plone, viewlets

Once again back with a Plone question.

I have Plone 4 installed and I need to show the Document action icons at the top instead of bottom. having trouble in getting this to work. can someone help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just need to move that viewlet (with same class and template), first you have to register a viewlet with same class to your desired viewletmanager (let's say for ex. `plone.app.layout.viewlets.interfaces.IAboveContentBody`):

```
<browser:viewlet
    name="plone.abovecontenttitle.documentactions"
    manager="plone.app.layout.viewlets.interfaces.IAboveContentBody"
    class="plone.app.layout.viewlets.content.DocumentActionsViewlet"
    permission="zope2.View"
    />
```

and then add this in your genericsetup profile (file `viewlets.xml`) :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<object>
 <order manager="plone.abovecontentbody" skinname="Plone Default">
  <!-- this will place your viewlet before all the others.
       you can also use a viewlet's name for a relative position -->
  <viewlet name="plone.abovecontenttitle.documentactions" insert-before="*"/>
 </order>

 <hidden manager="plone.belowcontentbody" skinname="Plone Default">
  <viewlet name="plone.abovecontenttitle.documentactions"/>
 </hidden>
</object>
```

More info:

- http://plone.org/documentation/kb/customization-for-developers/viewlets
- http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/views/viewlets.html